# Issue with record.setFieldValues() in SuiteScript Emptying Field Values

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

Ok, so I have a user event script attached to a custom record. One of the fields on this custom record is a select field for item records. In the user event script, it's getting the value of this field, checking the item options on the selected item. As it runs through the values, it checks to see if it's missing certain values and adds them if necessary. The problem I'm having is that it's ultimately setting the item options field to blank. I've tried both with loading the record, setting the values, then saving, and also by trying to just set a single value with nlapiSubmitField(). The outcome is the same both ways. Here's a quick rundown of the code:

```
var itemId = customRec.getFieldValue("custrec_item_field");
var itemRec = nlapiLoadRecord("noninventoryitem", itemId, { recordmode : "dynamic" });
var optArray = [ "CUSTCOL_OPT1" , "CUSTCOL_OPT2" , "CUSTCOL_OPT3" , "CUSTCOL_OPT4" ];
itemRec.setFieldValues("itemoptions", optArray);
nlapiSubmitRecord(itemRec, true, true);
```

Now, a few months back I was certain this was working correctly, and if I apply similar login to a user event BeforeSubmit function when the item record saves, everything works as intended. I'm sure I could get this to work by triggering an edit on the item record within a Suitelet called from the original user event, but that seems ridiculous. There are no errors encountered unless I pass in the item option values through in lower case. Am I missing something? Or am I just going to have to find a way to trigger this outside of this user event function?

Answer (score 1):

There was a flaw somewhere else that was clearing the options out because it mistakenly thought the selected value had changed.

Comment: Happens. Would suggest looking at the SuiteScript Debugger as while it is a little clunky it can make tracking down problems like this a lot easier.